# Nuxt and Vuetify, how to use color in components like v-toolbar

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Nuxt 2 and Vuetify 2.
I am trying to create a simple Vuetify `v-toolbar` component and give it a color.

De documentation tells me to do it like this:

```html
<template>
  <v-toolbar flat color="green"> <!-- this does not make the toolbar green! -->
    <v-toolbar-title>
      My title here
    </v-toolbar-title>
  </v-toolbar>
</template>
```

The `flat` attribute works, as it changes the appearance of the toolbar.

However, the `color="green"` attribute doesn't work as expected. The toolbar does not turn green.
When inspecting the html in my browser, I can see that the "green" property is added as a class to the markup:

```html
<header 
  data-v-3ece7af3="" 
  data-v-23162205="" 
  class="v-sheet theme--light v-toolbar v-toolbar--flat green" 
  style="height: 64px;">
```

I've setup Nuxt in the way that the Vuetify documentation suggests:

```js
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify'
  ],

  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    treeShake: true
  },
}
```

```
// assets/variables.scss
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Is the color available in your config? Maybe it's overwritten by something else?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying. I have not defined "green" anywhere, as I expect Vuetify to define it for me. I've tried other "material design" colors like "grey lighten-4" and those do not work either.

Comment: I'm not sure about your configuration but a freshly created project works fine with your template, just tested.

Comment: I'm trying to find out what is wrong with my configuration. I'm using nodejs with Nuxt as a plugin (using `app.use(nuxt.render);` and `build(nuxt)`;) and I do not see how to start with a clean Nuxt install.

Comment: Does your vuetify components wrapped inside `v-app` tag?

Comment: Node with Nuxt as a plugin? Never tried this one. The usual way to bootstrap a Nuxt project quickly is `npx create-nuxt-app my-cool-project`.

Comment: @NimaEbrazeh, your comment helped me fix my problem :-). Indeed I did not have a `v-app` tag in my application. Adding the `v-app` tag solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you forget to wrap your components inside `v-app` tag and this can solve your problem.